# Cannot close the workbook object while creating excel file

Tags: excel, groovy, apache-poi

There was requirement of some Excel manipulation in my project, so I was going through some online codes to understand how it works.

Now I am using groovy to create an Excel file at specified path with just two columns.

The code that I am using does in fact create an excel, but in the end while closing the workbook it fails throwing an exception.

this is the code I am using :

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Re-Trigger Incidents");

//creating font

Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
headerFont.setBold(true);
headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

// Create a Row
Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

//create a cell in Row

Cell cell1 = headerRow.createCell(0);
cell1.setCellValue("Incident Number");
cell1.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

Cell cell2 = headerRow.createCell(1);
cell2.setCellValue("Queue Incident was Present in");
cell2.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);

sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);


FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\MyFirstExcel.xlsx");
workbook.write(fileOut);

fileOut.close();

workbook.close();
```

and this fails while throwing an exception :

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.close() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: last(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.lang.Object), plus(java.lang.Iterable), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure)
```

I do not know why this is happening as far as I know the no argument close method should work fine.

Any idea what might I be missing, as I am new to this, I think I might have messed up something that somehow I am not able to notice

Comment: The code looks good but it's more like java code. How do you run it? Is it being run as groovy script? Can you share the command and groovy version?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? If not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy Yup. Code is being run as groovy script. I am using the groovy console to execute this code and the version of groovy is 2.4.12

Comment: if it is a script, you should not really care about closing at all ;)

Comment: @injecteer still why it doesn't get closed? This issue is bugging me, because as far as I know code is correct.

Comment: Well, obviously your version of the libra doesn't have close() method

Comment: I guess that must be it upgrading it to 4.1 solved the problem, the problem being faced was for poi 3.9 (earlier I was using all the jars of 3.9 version i.e. poi,poi-examples,poi-excelant,poi-ooxml,poi-ooxml-schemas)

Comment: I still don't understand if the close() method was not within 3.9 version what was being used to close the workbook, any idea? I cannot find any javadoc for the very same version to confirm.